# Will same Image Targets with different metadata works in cloud recognition (Vuforia)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I'm using unity with Vuforia integration, In my use case we have same image target with different metadata. So I'm getting only one metadata of an image target. Can anyone tell if it is possible to target same image with different metadata with cloud target recognition?

Answer (score 1):

Following statement quoted by Vuforia Engine Support. So you can't use a very similar image or same image with the same metadata since vuforia don't have any clue to differentiate the image. So it'll return first recognized object's metadata. I experienced the same problem but there is no way other than changing the image. The original [answer is here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/cloud-recognition/it-possible-identify-similar-multiple-cloud-targets-recognition-different-metadata).

> Hello,
>
> Unfortunately, these are essentially the same image. The only difference that I can see is the text in the lower-right corner. Vuforia is not optimized for text - this includes our Cloud Reco service.
>
> As the images are currently authored I know of no way for our product to differentiate on from the other. The only option would be to use a different image, but I'm guessing this is not possible as the book has already been printed?
>
> Sorry we cannot be of more help.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Vuforia Engine Support